# How to write this if() statment in java

Tags: javascript, java, if-statement

Hi I was wondering how do you write this in an if() statment in java?

"If either polonium dips below 0.75, spider_venom goes above 0.52, or perhaps sarin dips below 0.66, increase paracetamol by 0.01"

I wrote this but it is wrong.

```
if((polonium < 0.75 && spider_venom > 0.52) || (sarin < 0.66))
        {
           paracetamol += 0.01
        }
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? It likely wouldn't matter, the syntax for `if` would be the same, however, it'd be useful for you to know which technology you actually work with.

Comment: there shouldn't be a logical AND, just two logical OR's in that conditional statement

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.

Comment: Also, a tip "Either <A> or <B>" does not translate to `A && B` in code.

Comment: @Stultuske either-or is XOR. Although, the text does make it seem like a logical (inclusinve) OR might be needed. Not sure. EDIT: might also be three separate conditions as in if *two* are true, then act twice.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if(polonium < 0.75 || spider_venom > 0.52 || sarin < 0.66)
{
    paracetamol += 0.01
}
```

The reason your code is incorrect, is that you have an AND in the condition statement. Your conditions could be translated as, **IF any of those three conditions hold, THEN do increase paracetamol by 0.01**, which is just OR-ing all three statements.

Comment: it would be better if you also explained your change.